# Magento - Upload Image in Back Office

Tags: php, magento, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload an image in Sales Rules in Magento,

I follow this tutorial :

https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/How+to+create+an+image+or+video+uploader+for+the+Magento+Admin+Panel

My fields must be in native SalesRules Magento module , so I made overloading following files:

Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Form

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main
I add my field in _prepareForm() function

```
$fieldset->addField('image_promo', 'image', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Image'),
            'required'  => false,
            'name'      => 'image_promo',
    ));
```

and in this file, I change my return:

From

```
return parent::_prepareForm();
```

To

```
return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form::_prepareForm();
```

And finally I'm overloading this file :

Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_QuoteController and I'm adding to saveAction() function :

```
if(isset($_FILES['image_promo']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['image_promo']['tmp_name']))) {
                try {
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image_promo');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // or pdf or anything                

                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                    // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file in a folder the magento way
                    // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file directly in the $path folder
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;

                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['image_promo']['name']);

                    $data['image_promo'] = $_FILES['image_promo']['name'];
                }catch(Exception $e) {
                    Mage::logException($e);
                }
            }else {      

                if(isset($data['image_promo']['delete']) && $data['image_promo']['delete'] == 1)
                    $data['image_main'] = '';
                else
                    unset($data['image_promo']);
            }
```

When I try to save without upload any files, magento work properly, but when i have an image, i not pass through my saveAction, and i'm being redirected on Dashboard ...

I'm trying to had an hidden form_key by this way in my Main.php (Second file)

```
 $fieldset->addField('form_key', 'hidden', array(
            'value' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(),
            'name'  => 'form_key',
    ));
```

But this doesn't change anything !

Any idea ?